# Load HTML page into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqui

I have a problem with the following code on my website:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
       $("#gallery").load("html/gallery/gallery.html");
}
```

When it runs in Chrome, it works great, but when I run my site in Firefox it does not load the `gallery.html` page.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Are you running the site locally? Also, take a look at browser's debugging tools, it should have a **net** panel or something similar that would allow you to see the **ajax** request.

Comment: You haven't given enough information for us to help you with this issue.  It should work, but something in your code (the html of your gallery, etc) is causing the issue.  If you can give a little more information we could try to help.